# Class UserPolicy does not exist (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\gates_policies\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

This is my AuthServiceProvider file,

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use App\User;
use App\Policies\UserPolicy;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as 
ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * The policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    User::class => UserPolicy::class,
];

/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('display_msg','UserPolicy@display');
}
}
```

and in my blade file I am trying to display 'Hello World' Provided User is valid using Policies in Laravel.

Code of my Blade file:

@extends('layouts.app')

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                @if (session('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        {{ session('status') }}
                    </div>
                @endif

                I am User<br>

                @can('display_msg')
                Hello World
                @endcan
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Code in UserPolicy File:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
use HandlesAuthorization;

/**
 * Create a new policy instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

public function display(User $user)
{
    if($user->name == 'vrajesh')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I am getting the error:
Class UserPolicy does not exist (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\gates_policies\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Comment: this issue came from your blade page, please paste your blade page code here

Comment: @RAUSHAN KUMAR, I have added the code of my blade file.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved in a similar situation (Laravel 5.4) using the the command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

This command force composer to browse installed packages and recreate the vendor\autoload.php file (and also a few other related to auto loading of classes)

Comment: OK, but what does it do?

Comment: @NateS Added a little explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
Gate::define('display_msg','UserPolicy@display');
```

to:

```
Gate::define('display_msg','App\Policies\UserPolicy@display');
```

Comment: Error got removed, but not getting the message 'Hello World' yet. I tried directly returning true from display method.

Comment: Having the same trouble in Laravel 5.5. The funny thing is that in the Laravel example (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#gates) it's configured without the namespace.